# Removing multiple new lines (/r/n) from String

Tags: java, html-parsing, special-characters

I have textarea and I'm trying to process the text from it to remove multiple new lines, specifically if more than 2 new lines into maximum 2 new lines.
But somehow `String.replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\n")` doesn't seems to work.

Why?

I even see the replaced string when I look into it Hex code many
`0d0a0d0a0d0a0d0a0d`

For the reference this is the method what I'm using:

```
public static String formatCommentTextAsProvidedFromUser(String commentText) {
  commentText = commentText.trim();
  commentText = commentText.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n");
  commentText = commentText.replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\n");
  try {
    Logger.getLogger(CommonHtmlUtils.class.getName()).info("Formated = "  + String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, commentText.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(CommonHtmlUtils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  return commentText;
}
```

I'm confused. Why 0a 0d multiple times after replace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression. e.g.:

```
commentText = commentText.replaceAll("(\r?\n){3,}", "\r\n\r\n");
```

This replace 3 o more *newlines* into 2 newlines.

In another way, you may want to use the default system line separator:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

So,

```
commentText = commentText.replaceAll("(\r?\n){3,}", 
                                      lineSeparator + lineSeparator);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, do you mind perhaps looking into String.replace() implementation to tell me why my code didn't work? http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2Cjava.lang.CharSequence%29 . After 15 years with Java I don't understand why `replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\n")` didn't work.

Comment: Hi Paul, I could provide you my input but I did try to realize why? So that you could debug it for me? I was not lazy and run debug on it myself to see why that replace() did. I've seen that find() did return true in the matcher but my watch put in Matcher.java didn't work - most likely because it is compiled code. So it remains a mistery. If you want to try it, you can try with whatever i.e. `String test = "t\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\ntt";`